# Remove trailing slash in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

i have been having trouble with my htaccess. I tried removing the trailing slash, but get a error that says ["This webpage has a redirect loop"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T231.png).
My current htaccess is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)/$ $1
```

**Before you answer**
*I have already looked at other sources in stackoverflow, they all give me the same error, except some give me a "500 internal server error". So please don't post it as a duplicated* :)

Comment: yes, the "ErrorDocument 404 /404/" works i have tested it with and without it, that is not the problom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way in your root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/

RewriteEngine On

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache. After testing is complete change `302` to `301` to make it a permanent redirect.

Comment: i get a "Internal Server Error

Comment: F:/Apache/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteCond', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: i enabled it, but now i don't get a error but it dosn't remove "/"

Comment: localhost/404, localhost/css, localhost/default

Comment: how do i make it so it's a real directory and a non-real directory

Comment: `/` should not be removed from real directories since that is a security risk. For all non-directory URL above rule will work fine.

Comment: why is it a security risk??

Comment: Read **security warning** on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Comment: how does youtube do it?? so its youtube.com/watch?v=101 instead of youtube.com/watch/?v=101

Comment: Because `/watch/` is not a real directory. Also we cannot engage in long chat over this. You can search about this issue. I have already answered original problem in my answer.

Comment: last question, then how does it allow you to watch videos without it redirecting you to the 404 page, and when you type for example youtube.com/bob?v=101 it redirects u to youtube.com/watch?v=101

Comment: That is easy. It checks for presence of `/watch` at URL start and if that's not present it redirects to `/watch?...`